# Java - If I specify multiple generics, do I have to use them all?

Tags: java, generics

Say for example I create a class:

```
class Foo<A, B>{
 Some stuff...
}
```

Then when I want to use that class, do I have to specify something for both types?

```
Foo<Integer, String> bar = new Foo<Integer, String>(69, "AYY LMAO!");
```

or could I just use one? Eg:

```
Foo<Integer> bar = new Foo<Integer>(69);  OR
Foo<String> bar = new Foo<"AYY LMAO!">;
```

If I can't, can I just set of the types to null? Eg:

```
Foo<null, Integer> bar = new Foo<Integer>(69);  OR
Foo<String, null> bar = new Foo<String>("AYY LMAO!");
```

Thanks, and I hope it's not a stupid question. (Quite a lot of my questions get dislikes).

Comment: *Quite a lot of my questions get dislikes* - Maybe you should reevaluate your questions and figure out why they are getting downvoted before you get banned from asking :P (for example, this one...)

Comment: `new Foo<"AYY LMAO!">`???

Comment: `Foo<Integer, String> =`???

Comment: You can specify `Foo<String, ?>`.

Comment: a) Have you actually tried to see what happens? b) If both are required, couldn't you just use a dummy for one of them? c) If you want to do this it sounds like your design is wrong.

Comment: Ya thanks, I've edited it now, hope it makes more sense. I don't know if i was just baiting dislikes with that comment, but the error in the code definitely contributed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using generics*, you always need to include both types. Depending on your specific use, there are a couple of ways you could do this:

1. Use a wildcard for one of them:

   ```
   Foo<?, Integer> foo = new Foo<>(69);
   ```
2. Use the `Void` type:

   ```
   Foo<Void, Integer> foo = new Foo<>(69);
   ```

Both of these will prevent you from passing any value for `A` except for `null`. Return types for the first approach will be of type `Object`. For the second solution, they will be `Void`, which can only be `null`**, because it has no public constructor.

<sub>*You can use a raw type and specify *no* type parameters, but this is strongly discouraged.

**Unless you use reflection to instantiate it.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Yes, do have to specify them all. From [JLS Sec 4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5):

> A parameterized type C is well-formed if all of the following are true:
>
> - `C` is the name of a generic type.
> - The number of type arguments is the same as the number of type parameters in the generic declaration of *C*.
> - When subjected to capture conversion (§5.1.10) resulting in the type `C<X1,...,Xn>`, each type argument `Xi` is a subtype of `S[F1:=X1,...,Fn:=Xn]` for each bound type `S` in `Bi`.
>
> It is a compile-time error if a parameterized type is not well-formed.

Hence, if you don't have the same number of type arguments, the parameterized type is not well-formed, and so a compile-time error occurs.

If you don't want to provide a specific type for some of the type parameters, you should use a wildcard (`?`) as a placeholder, as it says [in the following section of the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1):

> Wildcards are useful in situations where only partial knowledge about the type parameter is required.